# dkim failure and hMailserver

Tags: dkim, hmail-server

I dont understand why i get failure with dkim from **verifier.port25.com**. I tried 5-6 times generating a new dkim key with private and public DNS record.

My mail server is **hmailserver version 5.6-1B2208**.

My domain is searchwar.dk and selector "dkim._domainkey.searchwar.dk".

I tried generating my own dkim key by openssl and with online generators like http://www.port25.com/support/domainkeysdkim-wizard/ and https://www.socketlabs.com/domainkey-dkim-generation-wizard/. Dont work at all. If you need more info from my server please ask.

**hmailserver dkim setup:**
selector: dkim

private key file: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Externals\CA\dkim-key-searchwar.pem

header methed: relaxed

body method: relaxed

signing algorthme: SHA1

**private key**

****REMOVED****

**txt record with public key**

```
"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC/6AlKG/TXFDEMRhrEuWjmLJvbplmA7E8Wg5/LWies3eDfDXZcThYrsGKMUbZl3cJ3Pm35mnDFZrbvPBZ80dB+YXr1ozQaYAEZ3AOzLMjd5q5e5u2ZDWa/qYN8myTgmfElHQ71QIvzIWLfk7ILeK2CEYLzBko84q46ol3FQUQTmQIDAQAB"
```

**verifier.port25.com response:**

```
his message is an automatic response from Port25's authentication verifier
service at verifier.port25.com.  The service allows email senders to perform
a simple check of various sender authentication mechanisms.  It is provided
free of charge, in the hope that it is useful to the email community.  While
it is not officially supported, we welcome any feedback you may have at
<verifier-feedback@port25.com>.

Thank you for using the verifier,

The Port25 Solutions, Inc. team

==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         fail
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================

HELO hostname:  mail.kimdamdev.dk
Source IP:      144.76.63.57
mail-from:      kim@searchwar.dk

----------------------------------------------------------
SPF check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass
ID(s) verified: smtp.mailfrom=kim@searchwar.dk
DNS record(s):
    searchwar.dk. SPF (no records)
    searchwar.dk. 86400 IN TXT "v=spf1 mx include:kimdamdev.dk ~all"
    searchwar.dk. 86400 IN MX 10 mail.kimdamdev.dk.
    mail.kimdamdev.dk. 77388 IN A 144.76.63.57

----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=kim@searchwar.dk
DNS record(s):

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         fail (wrong body hash: expected GfHcUrS2Mx51KGPEIXNr479RXIc=)
ID(s) verified:
Canonicalized Headers:
    from:"kim@searchwar.dk"'20'<kim@searchwar.dk>'0D''0A'
    subject:test'0D''0A'
    date:Thu,'20'12'20'Feb'20'2015'20'16:37:10'20'+0100'0D''0A'
    message-id:<2015021216371010202415@searchwar.dk>'0D''0A'
    to:check-auth'20'<check-auth@verifier.port25.com>'0D''0A'
    mime-version:1.0'0D''0A'
    content-type:multipart/alternative;'20'boundary="----=_001_NextPart388608083378_=----"'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha1;'20'd=searchwar.dk;'20's=dkim;'20'c=relaxed/relaxed;'20'q=dns/txt;'20'h=From:Subject:Date:Message-ID:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type;'20'bh=IqGZmHP6kTHOygz1cJKY+siENuA=;'20'b=

Canonicalized Body:
    This'20'is'20'a'20'multi-part'20'message'20'in'20'MIME'20'format.'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    ------=_001_NextPart388608083378_=----'0D''0A'
    Content-Type:'20'text/plain;'20'charset="us-ascii"'0D''0A'
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:'20'quoted-printable'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    test'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    kim@searchwar.dk'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    ---'0D''0A'
    Denne'20'e-mail'20'blev'20'kontrolleret'20'for'20'virusser'20'af'20'Avast'20'antivirussoftware.'0D''0A'
http://www.avast.com'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    ------=_001_NextPart388608083378_=----'0D''0A'
    Content-Type:'20'text/html;'20'charset="us-ascii"'0D''0A'
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:'20'quoted-printable'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    <html><head><meta'20'http-equiv=3D"content-type"'20'content=3D"text/html;'20'charset=3Dus-ascii"><style>body'20'{'20'line-height:'20'1.5;'20'}body'20'{'20'font-family:'20''27'Segoe'20'UI'27';'20'color:'20'rgb(0,'20'0,'20'0);'20'line-height:'20'1.5;'20'}</style></head><body>'0D''0A'
    <div><span></span>test</div>'0D''0A'
    <div><br></div><hr'20'style=3D"width:'20'210px;'20'height:'20'1px;"'20'color=3D"#b5c4df"'20'size=3D"1"'20'align=3D"left">'0D''0A'
    <div><span><div'20'style=3D"MARGIN:'20'10px;'20'FONT-FAMILY:'20'verdana;'20'FONT-SIZE:'20'10pt"><div>kim@searchwar.dk</div></div></span></div>'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    <br'20'/><br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    <hr'20'style=3D'27'border:none;'20'color:#909090;'20'background-color:#B0B0B0;'20'height:'20'1px;'20'width:'20'99%;'27''20'/>'0D''0A'
    <table'20'style=3D'27'border-collapse:collapse;border:none;'27'>'0D''0A'
    '20'<tr>'0D''0A'
    '20'<td'20'style=3D'27'border:none;padding:0px'20'15px'20'0px'20'8px'27'>'0D''0A'
'20'<a'20'href=3D"http://www.avast.com/">'0D''0A'
'20'<img'20'border=3D0'20'src=3D"http://static.avast.com/emails/avast-mail-stamp.png"'20'/>'0D''0A'
    '20'</a>'0D''0A'
    '20'</td>'0D''0A'
    '20'<td>'0D''0A'
    '20'<p'20'style=3D'27'color:#3d4d5a;'20'font-family:"Calibri","Verdana","Arial","Helvetica";'20'font-size:12pt;'27'>'0D''0A'
    '20'Denne'20'e-mail'20'blev'20'kontrolleret'20'for'20'virusser'20'af'20'Avast'20'antivirussoftware.'0D''0A'
'20'<br><a'20'href=3D"http://www.avast.com/">www.avast.com</a>'0D''0A'
    '20'</p>'0D''0A'
    '20'</td>'0D''0A'
    '20'</tr>'0D''0A'
    </table>'0D''0A'
    <br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    </body></html><br/>'0D''0A'
    <div'20'class=3D"sender'20'person">'0D''0A'
    <b>Med'20'venlig'20'hilsen</b><br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    Kim'20'Dam'20'Gronhoj<br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    Mobil:'20'+45'20'25363897<br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    E-mail:<a'20'href=3D"maito:Kim@Searchwar.dk">'20'Kim@Searchwar.dk</a><br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    <br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    Adresse:<br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    Mollevej'20'4,'20'1<br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    9400'20'Norresundby<br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    <br'20'/>'0D''0A'
    Linkedin:<br'20'/>'0D''0A'
<a'20'href=3D"https://www.linkedin.com/in/kimdg>https://www.linkedin.com/in/kimdg</a>'0D''0A'
    </div>'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    <br/><br/>'0D''0A'
-'20'You'20'dont'20'want'20'emails'20'from'20'us:'20'<a'20'href=3D"http://kimdamdev.dk/unsubscribe.html">Unsubscribe</a>'0D''0A'
    ------=_001_NextPart388608083378_=------'0D''0A'


DNS record(s):

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.

----------------------------------------------------------
Sender-ID check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass
ID(s) verified: header.From=kim@searchwar.dk
DNS record(s):
    searchwar.dk. SPF (no records)
    searchwar.dk. 86400 IN TXT "v=spf1 mx include:kimdamdev.dk ~all"
    searchwar.dk. 86400 IN MX 10 mail.kimdamdev.dk.
    mail.kimdamdev.dk. 77388 IN A 144.76.63.57

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin v3.4.0 (2014-02-07)

Result:         ham  (0.3 points, 5.0 required)

pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED          ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
                            See
http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
                             for more information.
                            [URIs: avast.com]
0.8 DKIM_ADSP_ALL          No valid author signature, domain signs all mail
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
-1.9 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
                            [score: 0.0000]
0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
1.1 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_16     BODY: HTML: images with 1200-1600 bytes of words
0.0 MIME_QP_LONG_LINE      RAW: Quoted-printable line longer than 76 chars
0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
0.1 HTML_SHORT_LINK_IMG_3  HTML is very short with a linked image
0.0 T_DKIM_INVALID         DKIM-Signature header exists but is not valid

==========================================================
Explanation of the possible results (from RFC 5451)
==========================================================

SPF and Sender-ID Results
=========================

"none"
      No policy records were published at the sender's DNS domain.

"neutral"
      The sender's ADMD has asserted that it cannot or does not
      want to assert whether or not the sending IP address is authorized
      to send mail using the sender's DNS domain.

"pass"
      The client is authorized by the sender's ADMD to inject or
      relay mail on behalf of the sender's DNS domain.

"policy"
     The client is authorized to inject or relay mail on behalf
      of the sender's DNS domain according to the authentication
      method's algorithm, but local policy dictates that the result is
      unacceptable.

"fail"
      This client is explicitly not authorized to inject or
      relay mail using the sender's DNS domain.

"softfail"
      The sender's ADMD believes the client was not authorized
      to inject or relay mail using the sender's DNS domain, but is
      unwilling to make a strong assertion to that effect.

"temperror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is likely transient in nature, such as a temporary inability to
      retrieve a policy record from DNS.  A later attempt may produce a
      final result.

"permerror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is unrecoverable, such as a required header field being absent or
      a syntax error in a retrieved DNS TXT record.  A later attempt is
      unlikely to produce a final result.


DKIM and DomainKeys Results
===========================

"none"
      The message was not signed.

"pass"
      The message was signed, the signature or signatures were
      acceptable to the verifier, and the signature(s) passed
      verification tests.

"fail"
      The message was signed and the signature or signatures were
      acceptable to the verifier, but they failed the verification
      test(s).

"policy"
      The message was signed but the signature or signatures were
      not acceptable to the verifier.

"neutral"
      The message was signed but the signature or signatures
      contained syntax errors or were not otherwise able to be
      processed.  This result SHOULD also be used for other
      failures not covered elsewhere in this list.

"temperror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is likely transient in nature, such as a temporary inability
      to retrieve a public key.  A later attempt may produce a
      final result.

"permerror"
      The message could not be verified due to some error that
      is unrecoverable, such as a required header field being
      absent. A later attempt is unlikely to produce a final result.


==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

Return-Path: <kim@searchwar.dk>
Received: from mail.kimdamdev.dk (144.76.63.57) by verifier.port25.com id hrj4ao20i3gc for <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>; Thu, 12 Feb 2015 10:37:16 -0500 (envelope-from <kim@searchwar.dk>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=kim@searchwar.dk
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed) header.From=kim@searchwar.dk
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=fail (wrong body hash: expected GfHcUrS2Mx51KGPEIXNr479RXIc=)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; sender-id=pass header.From=kim@searchwar.dk
dkim-signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; d=searchwar.dk; s=dkim;
c=relaxed/relaxed; q=dns/txt; h=From:Subject:Date:Message-ID:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type;
bh=IqGZmHP6kTHOygz1cJKY+siENuA=;
b=t+h7vKa5T5U2sHBP6orha4jOczM/zV36VI3CsyGDEZbs3aaDpAhWxdpq/Rsqp2bTC7MF+J4VY7EaEAqhGnzUWgLzYRKrGRdAp0ZrjXlClzyB29APCTf6FfQ7ud08kxsKc39gh/2l+8/YkkT3j5OI3iWNFhMJScr4adOWHmxlbLk=
Received: from kim (0x5552f0ae.adsl.cybercity.dk [85.82.240.174]) by mail.kimdamdev.dk
with ESMTPA ; Thu, 12 Feb 2015 16:37:07 +0100
Date: Thu, 12 Feb 2015 16:37:10 +0100
From: "kim@searchwar.dk" <kim@searchwar.dk>
To: check-auth <check-auth@verifier.port25.com>
Subject: test
X-Priority: 3
X-GUID: 0938D891-B72C-4DBD-9D82-FA9351576241
X-Has-Attach: no
X-Mailer: Foxmail 7, 2, 5, 140[en]
Mime-Version: 1.0
Message-ID: <2015021216371010202415@searchwar.dk>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_001_NextPart388608083378_=----"
X-Antivirus: avast! (VPS 150212-0, 02/12/2015), Outbound message
X-Antivirus-Status: Clean

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_001_NextPart388608083378_=----
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

test



kim@searchwar.dk


---
Denne e-mail blev kontrolleret for virusser af Avast antivirussoftware.
http://www.avast.com


------=_001_NextPart388608083378_=----
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><head><meta http-equiv=3D"content-type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii"><style>body { line-height: 1.5; }body { font-family: 'Segoe UI'; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.5; }</style></head><body>
<div><span></span>test</div>
<div><br></div><hr style=3D"width: 210px; height: 1px;" color=3D"#b5c4df" size=3D"1" align=3D"left">
<div><span><div style=3D"MARGIN: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: verdana; FONT-SIZE: 10pt"><div>kim@searchwar.dk</div></div></span></div>

<br /><br />
<hr style=3D'border:none; color:#909090; background-color:#B0B0B0; height: 1px; width: 99%;' />
<table style=3D'border-collapse:collapse;border:none;'>
<tr>
<td style=3D'border:none;padding:0px 15px 0px 8px'>
<a href=3D"http://www.avast.com/">
<img border=3D0 src=3D"http://static.avast.com/emails/avast-mail-stamp.png" />
</a>
</td>
<td>
<p style=3D'color:#3d4d5a; font-family:"Calibri","Verdana","Arial","Helvetica"; font-size:12pt;'>
Denne e-mail blev kontrolleret for virusser af Avast antivirussoftware.
<br><a href=3D"http://www.avast.com/">www.avast.com</a>
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
</body></html><br/>
<div class=3D"sender person">
<b>Med venlig hilsen</b><br />
Kim Dam Gronhoj<br />
Mobil: +45 25363897<br />
E-mail:<a href=3D"maito:Kim@Searchwar.dk"> Kim@Searchwar.dk</a><br />
<br />
Adresse:<br />
Mollevej 4, 1<br />
9400 Norresundby<br />
<br />
Linkedin:<br />
<a href=3D"https://www.linkedin.com/in/kimdg>https://www.linkedin.com/in/kimdg</a>
</div>

<br/><br/>
- You dont want emails from us: <a href=3D"http://kimdamdev.dk/unsubscribe.html">Unsubscribe</a>
------=_001_NextPart388608083378_=------
```

Comment: I don't think you want your private key exposed like this.  It somewhat defeats the purpose of DKIM, as anyone can use your private key to spoof email from your server.

Comment: Well, right now. Nothing works. They can use it.
 - I can always change the private key

Comment: I now changed my private key :) Thanks for your reminder

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In hmailserver, it is important that your server DONT allow "incorrectly formatted line endings" under the tab "RFC compliance" for "SMTP" protocals.

*- But when you enable this, the server will not allow sending emails with wrong formatted endings.*

My email client Foxmail had something wrong with LF